# How to use jquery in helpers on handlebars?

Tags: jquery, node.js, handlebars.js, helper

I'm working on a node.js project, and I'm using the handlebar template.

I am using partial and helper in router.js.

When using jquery in helper file, the following error occurs.

*** node error message**

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
at Object.exports.prnChart (/Volumes/MyStorage/[Project]/myweb/views/helpers/academy/hlp_ac_home.js:22:2)
at Object.eval [as main] (eval at createFunctionContext (/Volumes/MyStorage/[Project]/myweb/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/javascript-compiler.js:254:23), <anonymous>:6:201)
at main (/Volumes/MyStorage/[Project]/myweb/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/runtime.js:175:32)
at ret (/Volumes/MyStorage/[Project]/myweb/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/runtime.js:178:12)
at ret (/Volumes/MyStorage/[Project]/myweb/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/compiler.js:526:21)
at ExpressHandlebars._renderTemplate (/Volumes/MyStorage/[Project]/myweb/node_modules/express-handlebars/lib/express-handlebars.js:247:12)
at ExpressHandlebars.<anonymous> (/Volumes/MyStorage/[Project]/myweb/node_modules/express-handlebars/lib/express-handlebars.js:173:21)
```

*** app.js**

```
var express         = require( 'express' );
var exphbs          = require( 'express-handlebars' );

var ac_routes       = require( './routes/route' );

var app = express();

app.set( 'views', path.join( __dirname, 'views' ) );

var handlebars  = require( './views/helpers/hlp_basic.js' )( exphbs );
app.engine( 'hbs', handlebars.engine );
app.set( 'view engine', 'hbs' );

app.listen( 3000, function () {
    console.log( 'Cocle app listening on port 3000!' );
});
```

*** route.js**

```
var express = require( 'express' );
var request = require( 'request' );
var $ = require('jquery'); // not working!!

var router = express.Router();

router.get ( '/', function ( req, res ) {
    res.render( 'academy/ac_home', {
        helpers: require( __dirHelper + '/academy/hlp_ac_home' ),
        title: 'Ac. Home',
        layout_lnb: true,
        type: 'academy',
        page_style: 'academy',
        is_chart : true
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

*** hlp_ac_home.js**

```
var $ = require('jquery'); // not working!!

exports.prnChart = function ( target ) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://api.mydomain/list/chart.php',
        crossDomain : true,
        processData: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        data: jsonReq,
        success: function(data) {s
            console.log('response data : ',data);
            htmlDom = data.list;
        }, // Success Function
        error: function(xhr, res){
            console.log("Error code : " + xhr.status + "\nMessage : " + res);
        }
    });
    return htmlDom;
};
```

How do I use jquery in helper file(hlp_ac_home.js)?

Please help me- :)

Comment: Hmm... well, you can always use var jQuery = require('jquery');
And if that doesn't help well, did you install it?
npm i jquery

Comment: Yes, I have installed jquery.
The reason why var $ = require ('jquery') in hlp_ac_home does not work is because the template seems to have a special reason.

Comment: Should I apply the _dirname path to require?

Comment: @Nimrod P.
Thank you for your advice.
I solved the problem you raised.
require has installed jquery in node_module as a relative path.